# ios 6 assigning integers to multiple cells in tableview

Tags: ios, integer, tableview, cells

I've got a table in which I want to assign an integer for each cell that is clicked.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath



UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

Information *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Information1"];
```

This checks if cell text is equal to "player1" and assigns it an integer, and passes the title to the next view controller.

```
if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"John"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=0;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}



if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Mark"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=1;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}



if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Fred"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=2;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}


if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Matt"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=3;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}

if([[filteredSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Javier"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=3;

    [detailViewController setTitle:@"player 4"];



}

if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Andreas"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=4;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}

if([[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqual:@"Lionel"]){

    detailViewController.infoInt=5;

    [detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



}





[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

For my app this has to be done around 200 times and I was wondering if there was a way in which I could simplify my code. BTW I've got a property list that holds the name of all the players.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot more efficient to create an array of dictionaries from your array, so that it would look like this:

```
({@"player":@"John", @"num":@0},{@"player":@"Mark", @"num":@1},{@"player":@"Fred", @"num":@3}, etc}
```

Then you just need the 2 lines and no if statements:

```
   detailViewController.infoInt= playersearch[indexPath.row][@"num"];
   [detailViewController setTitle:playersearch[indexPath.row][@"player"]];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I know how to create an array of dictionaries but whats the purpose of ({@"player":@"John", @"num":@0},{@"player":@"Mark", @"num":@1},{@"player":@"Fred", @"num":@3}, etc}?

Comment: @AdrianFarfan, given your question, I thought you wanted to associate those particular numbers with those particular names. Is that not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If the assigned integers are equal to the cell indexes. Why dont you just do this :

```
[detailViewController setInfoInt:indexPath.row];
[detailViewController setTitle:[playersearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. That was very smart. Also, say I had implemented a search into that table view. And I have an array of filtered items.. when the items are filtered, the cell index and info int will change. I want to assign a new integer called extraInt to each item in the filtered search. How should I approach this?